# Identical Code Returning Opposite Results on Virtual Machine vs. Local PC

Tags: python, operating-system, virtual-machine

Okay, one really can't make this stuff up...
I have IDENTICAL code which works as expected on a Windows Virtual Machine, but works exactly the OPPOSITE to what's expected on my local Windows PC.

My code is meant to:
1. Check if a file exists in a folder.
2. Skip to next loop if it exists, else continue within current loop.

Please see the code below for further details.

`daily_links` is a list of URLs.
`path_to_db = os.path.join(r"path/to/folder/of/files/")`

```py
for link in daily_links:
    # Check if file already scraped and extracted:
    news_article_file_names = glob.glob(path_to_db + '*.csv')
    news_article_file_names = [name.split(os.sep)[-1] for name in news_article_file_names]

    recreated_file_name = link.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0] + '_withText.csv'

    # CORE PART OF THE PROBLEM:
    if recreated_file_name not in news_article_file_names:
        print(recreated_file_name)
```

On the Virtual Machine, the print statement shows all files that are NOT in the folder (as expected).

On the local PC, the print statement shows all files THAT ARE in the folder!

When I switch the code to this in the PC:

```py
    if recreated_file_name in news_article_file_names:
        print(recreated_file_name)
```

It prints all the files that are NOT in the folder.

I'm out of words here and can't believe my eyes.

But I've cross checked this, and had a colleague look at it too.

Any ideas?!

Comment: What are your guest and host OS'es and Python versions?

Comment: Both machines are on Windows 10 Enterprise. The local PC uses Python 3.6.4 while the Virtual Machine uses Python 3.7.3

Comment: Can you try [`print(os.listdir(path_to_db))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) on both machines to see if they find the same files?

Comment: The folders are different for each. I've got one folder for files in the virtual machine, and one for files in the local PC.

Comment: @Vash and do these different folders contain the same files?

Comment: @Ralf Nope, but both contain .csv files.